# Values wont reinsert after delete

Tags: php, mysql

I have a relational db.i need to do a update and reinsert. but all this is doing is deleting instead of re updating/inserting again

```
if($_POST['value_coming'] !=""){
  $delete_value_query=" DELETE  FROM values WHERE value_id='$value_id' ";
  $result=mysqli_query($connection,$delete_value_query);
  confirm_query($result);    
  foreach($_POST['value_coming'] as $value_coming_id){    
     $value_query="INSERT INTO values(value_id,value_coming_id)
   VALUES($student_id,$value_coming_id) ";  
    if($value_query && mysqli_affected_rows($connection)>0){
         echo "updated sucessully";
    }else{echo " could not update" . mysqli_error($connection);}  
 }//foreach end   
}
```

Comment: what does `var_dump($_POST['value_coming']);` return? Also, post us the "confirm_query" function. And sanitize.

Comment: returns the values that are selected coming in from the post array , its the correct values. this table does not have an auto increment field its connected to the $value id thats related to another table.

Comment: actually you're never reinserting the values. You're preparing the query, but you're not executing it. Maybe you wanted `if(mysqli_query($value_query) && mysqli_affected_rows($connection)>0)`? Anyway, you should sanitize your inputs before doing a query, you will never know what is coming into your $_POST, so it would be better to **escape** the values before querying them.

Comment: YOU are awsome!!!! that fixed it... Please i want to mark your answer

Comment: I don't want any mark for such a task, I'm just happy that you solved your problem :). If you want me to be happy, please sanitize your inputs, add a mysqli_real_escape_string to each of your array elements, your code is vulnerable to sql injections, it's important to protect your database from malicious attacks ;)

Comment: yes will do thanks. was just testing @ first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(mysqli_query($value_query) && mysqli_affected_rows($connection)>0)
```